# Do isolation transformers work within a voltage range?

Tags: transformer, circuit-protection

If I have an isolation (1:1) transformer rated for 240VAC at 20 amperes and then I apply 120VAC at 20 amperes, will the output over the load still be 120VAC at 20 amperes?

Comment: Why do you think "120VAC at 10 Amps?" Are you saying this because you are guessing that at 120 VAC there will only be 10 Amps at the primary because you are supplying half the RMS volts? (Which is wrong to think.) Or for some other reason, not stated, but meaningful in this case?

Comment: Applying 120V to a transformer rated for 240V/20A doesn't make the max current rating 10A, if this is your concern. As a general answer to your question, yes, a 1:1 240V isolation transformer will output 120V when 120V is applied. As long as you don't exceed 20A you're fine.

Comment: I just threw out 10 amps as a hypothetical to give a more definitive answer. I understand that a lower voltage doesn't mean a lower current. I am going to edit it to 20 amps because honestly thats more relevant to my situation anyways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use an isolation transformer below its rated voltage, it will be better in one sense, and worse in two senses.

Better - As the flux swing is lower, the core losses and no-load magnetising current will be smaller.

Worse - The most obvious is that as the current is limited to the rated current regardless of the voltage, the weight of the transformer will be twice what it would be if you used a transformer rated for your lower voltage at the same current.

The more subtle disadvantage is that the transformer regulation was probably aimed at about 5% at the higher voltage. When used at half the voltage, the voltage drop due to the current will be the same in volts, but now this drop will be assessed against the lower operating voltage, to give you 10% regulation. A transformer designed for the correct voltage will usually have the better regulation.

Answer (score 2):

Any voltage up to the maximum, and any current up to the maximum is fine from a power perspective, and to a first order for an isolation transformer, the output voltage will be the same as the input.

The only thing to watch is frequency.

Core saturation of magnetics (transformers, motors, etc) is generally tied to V/f.  If you are moving from a 60Hz system to a 50Hz system, you typically need to reduce the operating voltage (along with maximum power transfer), to maintain V/f.

However, for a 240V to 120V shift, you are probably increasing the frequency (or keeping the same), so no issue.

Answer (score 2):

VA capacity is proportional to somewhere between V and V^2, depending on how you're using it.  Up to a maximum limit determined by saturation (which is usually around rated voltage, so you don't get much if any additional capacity by turning up the voltage).

Suppose you have a 240V 1kVA transformer.  Suppose it is designed for 10% regulation, i.e. the output drops from say 252V open circuit, to 228V at rated load.  Rated load is 1kVA / 240V = 4.17A, so the output impedance is 5.7Ω.

If we operate the same transformer at 120V, it will have lower core losses (about 1/4), so run somewhat cooler, but the same voltage drop will be had with respect to load current; but the voltage is half, so the regulation is *two times worse*.

Whether regulation or temperature limits are controlling your application, I don't know, but it's generally a good idea not to compromise on regulation too much as it worsens the regulation of everything downstream, and reduces the available fault current -- excess current capacity means fuses blow quickly, limiting let-through energy.  With enough added impedance, a fault might simply sit there arcing away, and the nominal fuses never blow at all; the system acts like a current limiting welder supply rather than a safe and proper mains connection!

Anecdote: I was once testing a switching power supply prototype, using a 240V 500VA control transformer wired for 120V isolation.  So it introduced pretty significant impedance.  The power supply was only 200W or so, and being a regulated supply, the poor regulation wasn't a problem as such, at least for nominal operation.  Well, the inevitable happened, the main switching transistor failed; immediately, a jet of flame shot out of it, lasting perhaps half a second, until the fuse cleared -- a normal (fast) 2 or 3A glass type fuse.  No harm done, I wasn't hunched over it or anything, no flammable materials nearby, smell vented through windows, soot wiped off the surrounding area, replace parts and try again.  But you can see, the outcome might not always be so simple.

To be fair, the high fault current (typically low kA for residential circuits, up to ~100 kA for industrial) can still cause metal to vaporize, launch sharp fragments of plastic packages, etc.; safety glasses or other protection is recommended.  But risk of fire should at least be low in most work; the risk may be increased with lower fault current available, ironically enough.